# Using the result of a complex query later to combine with another query

Tags: mysql

I have a complex query which generates a simple single column id list, which I use to count the number of rows. Thereafter I need the IDs generated by the first query to combine with the result set of another ( second ) query. How can I preserve the result set of the first query to achieve the binding with the second query ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just use the first one as the basis for the second. Hopefully, this answer is as enigmatic as the question.

Comment: Sorry if the description of my question was not clear. Will try and better it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a temporary table:

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result AS [first long complex query here];

(You may wish to add an index here, depending on the nature of the rest of the work.)

//CREATE INDEX tmp_result_x ON tmp_result(some_col_name);

Comment: Here is my query ( with table names shortened).  
`code` SELECT mr.st_id 
    from mr,ar 
    where mr.mid = ar.st_id 
    and ar.aid = 1
    UNION
    SELECT ar.st_id
    from ar 
    WHERE ar.aid = 1 && ar.role <> 'master' `code`  
My query gives no errors and works fine every time when I run it in phpmyadmin. I get a result set. But when I enclose it in a CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE .. as suggested, it gives an error at line 5 near ( 'UNION SELECT..... ). Any suggestions ?

Comment: I tried this :  

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result 
SELECT st_id from ((
SELECT mr.st_id as st_id 
from mr,ar 
where mr.mid = ar.st_id 
and ar.aid = 1)
UNION
(SELECT ar.st_id as st_id
from ar
WHERE ar.aid = 1 && ar.role <> 'master')) tt

and it returns an empty table instead of the result set. Please advise.

Comment: @Ajoo, so now your comment is clearer than your question.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, I am improving already ! But I am still stuck with the issue. See if you can help me out now. Thanks again.

Comment: @ajoo we answer questions here, not comments. That's just how SO works. So, ask a better QUESTION .

Comment: @ Strawberry Hmm ! I have asked a question to which Murwiz has given a great reply and I have tried out his solution and it did work but only partially since the result set received was not as expected. I have even put the code here that I tried and the problem that I am now facing. 
Are you suggesting that I ask the same issue as a new question ?!

Comment: You can also create the index as you create the tmp table:  `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (INDEX(col)) SELECT ...;`